# Cannot include boost.asio

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am trying to include boost.asio library, but whenever I do that I get this error message:

```
 undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
```

I can include any other boost library, but not this one.

I tried to link boost.System like this:

```
icpc -lboost_system main.cpp -o out.o
```

It gave me this message

```
ld: cannot find -lboost_system
```

Comment: What platform are you on? Have you correctly installed Boost (including the binaries, not just headers)?

Comment: RedHat ... yes I did ... I can use other libraries and link other libraries ... my problem only with Boost.System, I can find it but I cannot link it :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to link `Boost.System` in order for Asio to work. [See here](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/using.html#boost_asio.using.dependencies).

Comment: I did but it could not find lboost_system

Comment: @turbonerd: [This](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#link-your-program-to-a-boost-library) might help. You should really read more documentation.

Answer (score 0):

As eluded to by @Space_C0wb0y, you need to either build Boost.System or use its correct name for linking (e.g. -lboost_system-mt).